# How to change TablePress default length

Tags: wordpress, datatable

I am using TablePress(tablepress.org) in my WordPress.

By default it shows 10 rows I want to show 3 rows.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in 2 ways:

1. **Through Table Edit screen**

   - Scroll down to find the **Features of the DataTables JavaScript library** section
   - Change the `Enable pagination of the table (viewing only a certain number of rows at a time) by the visitor.` value from `10` to `3`. See screenshot:

[image]

2. **Through Shortcode**

`[table id=1 datatables_paginate_entries=3 /]`

Here I assume your table id = `1`. You can change the number of rows by using `datatables_paginate_entries` parameter.

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-pagination-for-a-table/

Comment: I was using PHP method to call table and this helps me to achieve my goal.

Thank you so much :)